# Geometry problem for area of sight

Tags: python, geometry, pygame, line-of-sight

[image: Angles between the point on the top-right and the object]

My player have a line of sight and all objects between the white lines, turns red.
To compute this, the following conditions are met: if the angle between the yellow line and the red line are small or equal to the angle between the yellow line and the white line above, then the object is considered to be inside the line of sight. It also works if the object are below the white line. Here is the code:

```
def _getTeta(obj_1, obj_2):
    deltaX = (obj_1.centerx - obj_2.right)
    deltaY = (obj_2.top - obj_1.centery)
    return math.acos(deltaX / math.sqrt(deltaX**2 + deltaY**2))
```

> Obs.: *centerx* and *right* are X values and *centery* and *top* are Y value; all of them representing values encountered under certain points of each object's rectangle.

Then, I do:

```
if _getTeta(platform.rect, self.rect) <= _getTeta(abovePoint, self.rect):
    return True
```

where **above point** is the point in which forms the white line on the top, and **platform** is the object to be checked.

[image: Looking to the left is not working]

However, as the second image shows, it doesn't work if the line of sight are inverted in the X axis. The problem is that I don't know how to set values right so it could also work when the player is looking to the left.

Let me know if I'm not being clear in my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out in a simple way.

First, I set the mouse position with a value relative to the player's position, making the last the center (0,0).

Second, what python was doing is to set a 180 angle degrees in a clock direction above the player and another 180 angle degrees in a clockwise direction below the player. As anyone can see, this makes a huge mess.

The solution was to make a simple calculation with angles:

```
if mouse.y < player.y:
    sightAngle = 2*pi - mouseAngle
```

This basically makes a true 360 angle degree around the player, making the sen() and cos() work properly. And then, the coordinate position of the points is set according to the window's coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigonometric functions for this. With fairly simple vector algebra, this can work for any viewing direction. Consider the normalised vector **n** (the yellow line) and a vector pointing to an object, **x**. The object is in the field of view if: ***n*** · **x** > a |**x**|, where *a* is a number between -1 and 1 indicating the view angle (*cos φ/2 = a*).

In components (2D), using ***n***=(u,v) and ***x***=(x,y):

```
if (u*x + v*y > a * sqrt(x²+y²)) return true;
```

Comment: ALso, just use Math.Abs(x) and perform the operation independently for each side of the Y-axis.

Comment: So  φ is the total angle that I want for the line of sight?

Comment: @epiplon: Correct. In your drawing, it is the angle between the two white lines.

Comment: It didn't work or I missed something.

Comment: @epiplon: Could you post your code?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/4unmC7Gm

Comment: @epiplon: You have equated **x** and **n** to the location of the platform and the player, respectively. Instead, **x** should be the vector from player to target, i.e. (platform - self). The vector **n** merely indicates where the player is looking, e.g. straight right would probably be ***n** = (1,0)*.

Answer (score 0):

You just nee to use the absolute value of x --> abs(x)